# A signal/slot system like Qt with Wpf and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, qt

I would like to know if there is a similar system like the signal/slot of Qt in Wpf/c#

In other words, this is I would like to have :

myView.cs

```
public partial class myWindow :Window
{

    protected MyLambdaCollectionVM _myLambdaCollection;

    public myWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myLambdaCollection = new MyLambdaCollectionVM ();
        connect(this._myLambdaCollection, (SIGNAL(WhenIAddAnObject(str fileName)), SLOT(this.funcCalledWhenIaddAnObject(str fileName)));
    }
}
```

`connect(...)` is a Qt style signal/slot.

I've try binding method, but in my case, I need to create dynamically images (so not in Xaml but in C#) and I didn't find how to realize a C# to C# binding in WPF.

Comment: English version is enough

Comment: This site use **English** as a language. From http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/ `It is not our goal to teach English. It is our goal to teach programming. If the post has salvageable English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved just like any other post. If it does not, it should be closed`.

Comment: Based on [this signals and slots documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html), the signals and slots would be roughly equivalent with .net's delegates, making Mahmoud's answer perfect. None the less you should probably look into WPF-specific ways of doing what you want: for example, the example in the documentation might be better translated using Data Binding, not with events or routed events. You might want to ask for specific help on a specific problem, there might a better, simpler, more efficient WPF way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

in C# it it is called Events and Delegates and connect is replaced with something called event wiring.

```
myEventSource.EventName += new delegate(method to be called);
```

This is a roughly how it looks like in C#

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at TPL Dataflow. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx

Examples exist for GUI applications.